# How to use mod_pagespeed with Amazon S3 and CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

We have assets currently hosted on Amazon S3. I am looking into using CloudFront as a CDN but I am wondering how that will work with mod_pagespeed. The web server isn't hosted on EC2, it is hosted in another data center.

I believe CloudFront would directly pull the assets from S3. Since this is happening, how is mod_pagespeed involved? Do we need to spin up an EC2 instance and use it a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

If CloudFront is pulling directly from S3, then your Apache server running mod_pagespeed is not involved at all, in any way.

You could setup an EC2 instance running mod_pagespeed and point CloudFront to that. It sounds like you have a server already running mod_pagespeed, that isn't hosted on AWS. You could just point CloudFront to that server.

Comment: Thanks, we will probably just set up a new EC2 instance and do it that way. I don't really want to use the existing server because then we will be transferring data in and out of Amazon several times.

Comment: Have you ever set up an EC2 instance to do this? I set up EC2 as a proxy and am have a tough time getting it working so that it resizes images.

Comment: Sorry I've never used pagespeed. You might want to post a new question detailing the issues you are having.